# How to get variable name from JComboBox getSelectedItem

Tags: java, string, windows, combobox, jcombobox

I am experiencing a problem. I need to get a variable name from JComboBox function called .getSelectedItem(). But I am getting a value of a variable. For example:

String concern = "hello world";
String concern1 = "hello there";

String[] servers = {concern, concern1};
comboBox1 = new JComboBox(servers);

public String = selected;
selected = comboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();

And I need to write name of a variable(e.x. concern) to "selected" variable(like write concern to selected as String), but I am getting "hello world" written to selected. How can I fix that?

Comment: what is a valuable?

Comment: Do you mean "variable name"?

Comment: String concern = "hi";   I need to write exactly name concern, not "hi"

Comment: @resueman yes, sorry for mistake :C

Comment: @NaveUnown I'm pretty sure there's not going to be a way to do what you want. Variable names get lost when you compile the program. If you want to print those values, you need to store them in a variable, not just as the name.

Comment: @resueman that horrible.. I will try to do my best to resolve this problem. Write your coment as an answer. Ty :D